# Using arrays / other methods for optimization

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this code that is used to forecast predicted/ actual values essentially (units produced from a department) and the predicted values are extracted from a folder where I have 100 csv files labeled 1-100. I tell the program to go back into files before and compare it to the actual value produced( which is given in the basefile/baseheader.) Essentially every file has the actual units produced for the current month an then has a 12 month forecast. I have used this program to calculate it, however it runs verrry slowly. It takes over 30 seconds for a graph to appear when the range I specify is on the larger side, however if I am just seeing the range of a few months, it is quiet fast. I was told that I need to change the part of my code that says onetotal,twototal,threetotal, etc and change them into arrays. However, I am unsure how to go about this and I would not know how to plot exact values later on ( because I need to plot onetotal, then two total, etc ( and then show the distribution of values from onetotallist,twototallist, and so on) Any idea on how to approach this problem to speed up the program?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Beginning part of code is user input and calcultions to determine the Department,Range, and there is a function called getfileheader


def nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n):
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber) + ".csv", encoding="Latin-1")
    baseheader = getfileheader(basefilenumber)
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[
        basefileread["Customer"].str.contains(Department, na=False), baseheader
    ]

    nmonthread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber - n) + ".csv", encoding="Latin-1")
    nmonthvalue = nmonthread.loc[
        nmonthread["Customer"].str.contains(Department, na=False), baseheader
    ]

    return (
        (1 - (int(basefilevalue) / int(nmonthvalue)) + 1)
        if int(nmonthvalue) > int(basefilevalue)
        else int(nmonthvalue) / int(basefilevalue)
    )


N = 13
total = [0] * N
total_by_month_list = [[] for _ in range(N)]
for basefilenumber in range(int(StartRange), int(EndRange)):
    for n in range(N):
        total[n] += nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n)
        total_by_month_list[n].append(nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n))

onetotal=total[1]/ Range
twototal=total[2]/ Range
threetotal=total[3]/ Range
fourtotal=total[4]/ Range
fivetotal=total[5]/ Range
sixtotal=total[6]/ Range
seventotal=total[7]/ Range
eighttotal=total[8]/ Range
ninetotal=total[9]/ Range
tentotal=total[10]/ Range
eleventotal=total[11]/ Range
twelvetotal=total[12]/ Range
onetotallist=total_by_month_list[1]
twototallist=total_by_month_list[2]
threetotallist=total_by_month_list[3]
fourtotallist=total_by_month_list[4]
fivetotallist=total_by_month_list[5]
sixtotallist=total_by_month_list[6]
seventotallist=total_by_month_list[7]
eighttotallist=total_by_month_list[8]
ninetotallist=total_by_month_list[9]
tentotallist=total_by_month_list[10]
eleventotallist=total_by_month_list[11]
twelvetotallist=total_by_month_list[12]






x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
y = [
    onetotal,
    twototal,
    threetotal,
    fourtotal,
    fivetotal,
    sixtotal,
    seventotal,
    eighttotal,
    ninetotal,
    tentotal,
    eleventotal,
    twelvetotal,
]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
w = [
    (onetotallist),
    (twototallist),
    (threetotallist),
    (fourtotallist),
    (fivetotallist),
    (sixtotallist),
    (seventotallist),
    (eighttotallist),
    (ninetotallist),
    (tentotallist),
    (eleventotallist),
    (twelvetotallist),
]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for ze, we in zip(z, w):
    plt.scatter([ze] * len(we), we, marker="D", s=5)


plt.xlabel("Number of months forecast")
plt.ylabel("Predicted/Actual ratio")
plt.title("Predicted to actual ratio for n month forecast")
ax.plot(x, y, label="Predicted/Actual")
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(a, b, str(round(b, 2)))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Here is a dummy csv file: 
[image]

And my graph(if curious) 
[image]

Comment: You already have `total` and `total_by_month_list` ... why do you need these additional `...total` and `...totallist` variables anyway?

Comment: @AKX Because I take these variable and plot them to produce the graph I have displayed, unless there is another way to do that that I am unaware of?

Comment: You don't have to extract the variables from the lists in order to use them for your graph. Mind adding the Matplotlib code you've omitted, too? :)

Comment: @AKX Okay I added it in!

Comment: Okay, thanks. Let me see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, a couple of things:

- You were reading each file 24 times (twice for each N).
- There was that needless repetition in generating x/y/z/w

The optimizations/changes I made are, roughly:

- Using the lru_cache decorator to make sure each file is only read once (and kept in memory; if this is a problem, you can limit the size of the lru cache -- see the docs)
- Using zero-based indexes for the lists (0..11); this is idiomatic for Python.

Please be aware that this was dry-coded, so there may be some mistakes or omissions :)

---

```
import functools

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Department = ...
Range = ...
StartRange = ...
EndRange = ...


# The lru_cache decorator will ensure each file is read into memory only once (and kept there)
@functools.lru_cache()
def read_file(n):
    return pd.read_csv(str(n) + ".csv", encoding="Latin-1")


def nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n):
    basefileread = read_file(basefilenumber)
    baseheader = getfileheader(basefilenumber)
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[
        basefileread["Customer"].str.contains(Department, na=False), baseheader
    ]

    nmonthread = read_file(basefilenumber - n)
    nmonthvalue = nmonthread.loc[
        nmonthread["Customer"].str.contains(Department, na=False), baseheader
    ]

    return (
        (1 - (int(basefilevalue) / int(nmonthvalue)) + 1)
        if int(nmonthvalue) > int(basefilevalue)
        else int(nmonthvalue) / int(basefilevalue)
    )


N = 12
total_by_month_list = [[] for _ in range(N)]
for basefilenumber in range(int(StartRange), int(EndRange)):
    for n in range(N):
        # note "n+1" below since n is now zero-indexed
        total_by_month_list[n].append(nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n + 1))

total = [sum(by_month) for by_month in total_by_month_list]

x = list(range(1, N + 1))  # [1..12]
y = [t / Range for t in total]
z = x  # same as x
w = total_by_month_list

# ... matplotlib code ...
```

Comment: Wow that looks great! Thank you for the explanations as well. Let me try to implement it in my code and I'll let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: My graph literally appears instantly now! Thank you so much. This was a great learning experience as well because I did not know about the functools portion of your code. Again, thanks alot!

Comment: hi, so the next part of my program actually requires me to conduct equations on variables such as the variable I had set as onetotal. Is there a way from this code to still set onetotal so I can do calculations such as this: onetotaladjusted = onetotal * 1.2?

Comment: You can use list comprehensions to adjust the entire array: `adjusted = [value * 1.2 for value in total]`.

Comment: So there would be no way to do it individually? because I have to have different equations for each of them ( onetotal may be multiplied by 1.2 where twototal may be multipled by 1.5 and so on )

Comment: If you are curious, this part is to use the average number ( labeled in the graph) onetotal is = 1.07 in my graph and use that number to adjust future forecasts from incoming files... since we tend to over forecast by 1.07 evertime, my suggussted forecast adjustment would be to use the current value in the file ( lets say if we make a forecast for september 2018) and multiply it by 1/1.07 ( the value of onetotal) so its a suggested adjustment

Comment: I have edited my post to show what I was doing before, would you recccomend I start this as a new question. I just wanted to know if using this code is a feasible route to use and would appreciate any insight. Thank you !

Comment: A new question would be better.

Comment: But anyway, for "onetotal may be multiplied by 1.2 where twototal may be multipled by 1.5 and so on", you can do elementwise multiplication in a list comprehension using `zip` like this: `[value * multiplier for (value, multiplier) in zip(total, [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, ...])]`

Comment: Okay I will play around with that and also ask a new question, thanks!